# why the code of python2.7 have no any output?

Tags: beautifulsoup

This is an example from a python book.  When I run it I don't get any output.  Can someone help me?  Thanks!!!

```
from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

text = urlopen('https://python.org/community/jobs').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

jobs = set()
for header in soup('h3'):
    links = header('a', 'reference')
    if not links: continue
    link = links[0]
    jobs.add('%s (%s)' % (link.string, link['href']))
    print jobs.add('%s (%s)' % (link.string, link['href']))

print '\n'.join(sorted(jobs, key=lambda s: s.lower()))
```

reedit--
 firstly,i only considered the url is wrong but ignore the html infomation i wanna to get was not exist. May be this is why i get empty output.

Comment: At a guess, I'd say that either `soup(h3)` is empty or `links` is always empty. Could you update this question with the sort of text that you expect to get back from your `urlopen` line?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the page and inspect the html you'll notice there are no `<h3>` tags containing links. This is why you have no output.

So `if not links: continue` always continues.

This is probably because the page has moved to https://www.python.org/jobs/ so the `<h3>` tags containing links on the page are no longer present.

If you point this code's url to the new page. I'd suggest using taking some time to familiarize yourself with the page source. For instance it uses `<h2>` instead of `<h3>` tags for its links.